# Pass dynamically generated select box name into $_POST array

Tags: wordpress, widget

To make an WordPress widget I created a select box which gets options generated dynamically from $post object. The select box's name is also generated by dynamically. Here is the code

```
<select class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'employee' );?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'employee' ); ?>">
```

Results this :

```
<select class="widefat" name="widget-employee[13][department]" id="widget-employee-13-department">
```

To check the value of the select box I need to pass it to $_POST Array.

How do I pass the select box's value to $_POST array ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On submit, the `$_POST` variable will contain all the input fields/selected values etc. from your form in it. You don't have to manually add anything. You can manually pull info **from** your `$_POST` variable...

Comment: Well I actually need to compare $_POST variable value against another variable. In case of pulling the info from $_POST what should I write in this case $_POST['??????']. I want to  check $post->post_title == $_POST['???']. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess that in your select case you'd check against `$_POST['widget-employee'][13][department]` or something kinda like that. Try to see what you have in your `$_POST` variable (`print_r($_POST)`).

Comment: Your guess is right. Would you mind if I ask one more thing? I have two options in the select box. Like $_POST['widget-employee'][12][department] and $_POST['widget-employee'][13][department]. I want to populate number 12 & 13 dynamically to get the department value. Should I use for loop? OR there is another easy way? 

i.e If I choose option 1 it load $_POST['widget-employee'][12][department] value and if i chose option 2 it will load $_POST['widget-employee'][13][department] value and print that.

Comment: If there are just 2 options, just use `if`. Otherwise you can use either `foreach` to loop through an array, or `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On submit, the `$_POST` variable will contain all the input fields/selected values etc. from your form in it. You don't have to manually add anything. You can manually pull info from your `$_POST` variable if you wish.

You said you want to check `$_POST` against your value (`$post->post_title`), in that case, since your select has a name

```
widget-employee[13][department]
```

You'll use something like

```
$_POST['widget-employee'][13][department]
```

The best bet is to just use `print_r($_POST)` to see the contents of your `$_POST` variable and see what is in it, so that you can check against.